# Erro ao fazer uma requisição GET, JavaScript, Angular, Spring, Java

Tags: java, angularjs, jpa, spring, spring-boot

Estou com um erro ao abrir a tela com o resultado das buscas no banco. 
o erro está na imagem abaixo.

Fazendo o Debug, os dados estão vindo do banco de dados.

Na outra imagem, aparece o Log do servidor

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image]

Minha classe Bairros

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Bairros", schema="glb")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Bairros.findAll", query = "SELECT b FROM Bairros b"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Bairros.findByIdbairro", query = "SELECT b FROM Bairros b WHERE b.bairrosPK.idbairro = :idbairro"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Bairros.findByNome", query = "SELECT b FROM Bairros b WHERE b.nome = :nome"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Bairros.findByCodigodne", query = "SELECT b FROM Bairros b WHERE b.codigodne = :codigodne"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Bairros.findByIdentidade", query = "SELECT b FROM Bairros b WHERE b.bairrosPK.identidade = :identidade")})
public class Bairros  {


    @EmbeddedId
    protected BairrosPK bairrosPK;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 70)
    @Column(name = "Nome")
    private String nome;
    @Size(max = 8)
    @Column(name = "Codigo_dne")
    private String codigodne;
   /* @JoinTable(name = "Logradouros_bairros", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "Id_entidade", referencedColumnName = "Id_entidade"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "Id_bairro", referencedColumnName = "Id_bairro")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "Id_entidade", referencedColumnName = "Id_entidade"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "Id_logradouro", referencedColumnName = "Id_logradouro")})*/
   /* @ManyToMany
    private Collection<Logradouros> logradourosCollection;*/

    @JoinColumn(name = "Id_entidade", referencedColumnName = "Id_entidade", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Entidades entidades;
    @JoinColumn(name = "Id_municipio", referencedColumnName = "Id_municipio")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)

    private Municipios idmunicipio;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "bairros")
    private Collection<Pessoasenderecos> pessoasenderecosCollection;

    public Bairros() {
    }

    public Bairros(BairrosPK bairrosPK) {
        this.bairrosPK = bairrosPK;
    }

    public Bairros(BairrosPK bairrosPK, String nome) {
        this.bairrosPK = bairrosPK;
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public Bairros(long idbairro, long identidade) {
        this.bairrosPK = new BairrosPK(idbairro, identidade);
    }

    public BairrosPK getBairrosPK() {
        return bairrosPK;
    }

    public void setBairrosPK(BairrosPK bairrosPK) {
        this.bairrosPK = bairrosPK;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getCodigodne() {
        return codigodne;
    }

    public void setCodigodne(String codigodne) {
        this.codigodne = codigodne;
    }

 /*@XmlTransient
    public Collection<Logradouros> getLogradourosCollection() {
        return logradourosCollection;
    }

    public void setLogradourosCollection(Collection<Logradouros> logradourosCollection) {
        this.logradourosCollection = logradourosCollection;
    }*/

    public Entidades getEntidades() {
        return entidades;
    }

    public void setEntidades(Entidades entidades) {
        this.entidades = entidades;
    }

    public Municipios getIdmunicipio() {
        return idmunicipio;
    }

    public void setIdmunicipio(Municipios idmunicipio) {
        this.idmunicipio = idmunicipio;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<Pessoasenderecos> getPessoasenderecosCollection() {
        return pessoasenderecosCollection;
    }

    public void setPessoasenderecosCollection(Collection<Pessoasenderecos> pessoasenderecosCollection) {
        this.pessoasenderecosCollection = pessoasenderecosCollection;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (bairrosPK != null ? bairrosPK.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Bairros)) {
            return false;
        }
        Bairros other = (Bairros) object;
        if ((this.bairrosPK == null && other.bairrosPK != null) || (this.bairrosPK != null && !this.bairrosPK.equals(other.bairrosPK))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "br.marcars.m3.hibernate.Bairros[ bairrosPK=" + bairrosPK + " ]";
    }

}
```

Minha Classe BairroController Java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping (value="/user")
public class BairrosController {


    @Autowired
    BairrosService bairrosService;

    //end Points

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/bairros", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Bairros> cadastrarBairros(@RequestBody Bairros bairros) {
        Bairros bairrosCadastrado = bairrosService.cadastrar(bairros);
        return new ResponseEntity<Bairros>(bairrosCadastrado, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/bairros", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Collection<Bairros>> buscarTodosBairros() {
        Collection<Bairros> bairrosBuscados = bairrosService.buscarTodos();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(bairrosBuscados, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/bairros/{id}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Bairros> buscarBairrosPorId(@PathVariable int id) {
        Bairros bairros = bairrosService.buscaPorId(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(bairros, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.DELETE, value = "/bairros/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Bairros> excluirBairros(@PathVariable int id) {
        Bairros bairroEncontrado = bairrosService.buscaPorId(id);
        if (bairroEncontrado == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        bairrosService.excluir(bairroEncontrado);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value = "/bairros", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Bairros> alterarBairros(@RequestBody Bairros bairros) {
        Bairros bairroAlterado = bairrosService.alterar(bairros);
        return new ResponseEntity<Bairros>(bairroAlterado, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

Classe BairroCOntroller.js

```
app.controller("buscaBairroController", function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.bairros = [];
    $scope.bairro = {}; // binding com o form

    carregarBairros = function() {

        token = localStorage.getItem("userToken");


        $http({
            method : 'GET',
            url : 'http://localhost:8080/user/bairros'
        }).then(function(response) {
            $scope.bairros = response.data;

        }, function(response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            console.log(response.status);
        });
    };



    $scope.salvarBairros = function() {
        if ($scope.frmBairro.$valid) {
            $http({
                method : 'POST',
                url : 'http://localhost:8080/user/bairros',
                data : $scope.bairro
            }).then(function(response) {
                $("#modalSalvoSucesso").modal("show");
                carregarBairros();
                $scope.bairro = {};

            }, function(response) {
                console.log(response.data);
                console.log(response.status);
            });

        } else {
            $("#modalCampoObrigatorio").modal("show");

        }

    };

    $scope.excluirBairros = function(bairro) {
        bootbox.confirm({
            message : "Deseja excluir o registro permanentemente ?",
            buttons : {
                cancel : {
                    label : '<i class="fa fa-times"></i> Cancelar'
                },
                confirm : {
                    label : '<i class="fa fa-check"></i> Sim'
                }
            },
            callback : function(result) {
                if (result == true) {
                    $http({
                        method : 'DELETE',
                        url : 'http://localhost:8080/user/bairros/'+bairro.id
                    }).then(function(response) {

                        pos = $scope.bairros.indexOf(bairro);
                        $scope.bairros.splice(pos, 1);

                    }, function(response) {
                        console.log(response.data);
                        console.log(response.status);
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    };

    $scope.alterarBairros = function(bar) {
        $scope.bairro = angular.copy(bar);
    };

    $scope.cancelarAlteracaoBairros = function() {
        $scope.bairro = {};
    };

    carregarBairros();

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Para solucionar este erro foi feito o seguinte, 
Nas relações `@OneToMany` e `@ManyToOne` foi colocado uma anotação `@JsonIgnore` e foi importado o jar jackson-databind. Aparentemente resolveu a questão.